# Need demos of using hadoop cloudera

Tags: java, hadoop, cloudera

I am a begineer in hadoop. I understand the basic workflow of using map reduce. I have written a few basic stand alone programs in eclipse using the hadoop apis. 
I want do get into the real stuff and have some hands on. 
As of now i have downloaded the cloudera vmdk and installed it on VMWare Fusion.

Can somebody point me to the right location where i can find crystal clear info how to continue forward. 
I want to use hdfs on 2 or more machines and write some stand alone applications that uses these system resources to do parallel computing to solve my task. All oven the internet i have just found the understanding of map reduce and many advanced topics but nothing specific i am looking for.

Kindly direct me to the right place where i can find the tutorial or a video lecture to help me move forward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Kindly direct me to the right place where i can find the tutorial or a video lecture to help me move forward

This is the question which keeps on popping again and again in the forums. [Here](http://www.thecloudavenue.com/p/hadoop-mapreduce-resources.html) is the consolidated list of Hadoop material which I found interesting over time.

MapReduce can be used to solve a lot of interesting algorithms. Check [this](http://atbrox.com/2011/05/16/mapreduce-hadoop-algorithms-in-academic-papers-4th-update-may-2011/) and [this](http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~jimmylin/MapReduce-book-final.pdf) for the various algorithms than can be implemented on top of MapReduce. Pick a topic of your interest and start implementing it, then you will get comfortable with Hadoop/MapReduce.